# Inline MATLAB code

Tags: sourcecode, matlab

I want to write MATLAB code in a sentence.

I installed package `mcode`, no problem if I want to display the code by inserting the code in environment `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.

How could I possibly insert the MATLAB code in a sentence?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) provides `\mcode{<code>}` for inline MATLAB code. The following example is taken almost verbatim from the demo documentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package
\usepackage{mcode}
\begin{document}
This inline demo \mcode{for i=1:3, disp('cool'); end;} uses \verb|\mcode{}|.
\end{document}
```

Fundamentally, `mcode` uses [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) but sets all the appropriate keys so you don't have to worry about setting it yourself.

For full-width listings, use the regular `lstlisting` environment rather than `verbatim`, since the formatting will otherwise be different (again, taken verbatim from the documentation demo):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:3
    if i >= 5                   % literate programming replacement
        disp('cool');          % comment with some Â§\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$Â§
    end
    [~,ind] = max(vec);
    x_last = x(1,end);
    v(end);
    really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

`listings` also provide a `language=Matlab` setting, but the formatting differs from that provided by `mcode`.